# how to protect video files (.swf player) from hacker??

Tags: php, encryption, flash

I am facing a problem in protect **Video files** from hacker.How can i protect or prevent ?? Suggest me with any player that using password protection or encrypt the video. Help me with some example coding.

Regards,
Shahana

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to people saving the videos, there is no way to block it.

You are sending content to the clients, this means You can't stop them from saving it.

Even Google can't stop people from downloading and saving youtube videos.

There is nothing in the world stopping me from using a screen video capture software such as [these](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/win-screen-recording-softwares/) and save your video file.

The best thing you can do is adding watermarks to your videos.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Even though there is some site, having  videos protection by password.

Comment: Then Only people with password can download it if they want

Comment: yes, you right, But cant change or post in any website because code is in embedded format.